# How to sort a ListArray of custom object with a String "Date" member

Tags: java, sorting, date, arraylist

I have a ListArray of "Planning".

```
ArrayList<Planning> tmpListPlanning
```

Here's my "Planning Class":

```
public class Planning {
    private String start;
    private String title;

}
```

The thing is, I recieve the elements of my "tmpListPlanning" **in disorder**.

I would like to sort them with their date.
The date has this format:

```
"2013-12-10 14:00:00"
```

I saw this on StackOverFlow but I couldn't make it work on a list of custom object :

```
Collections.sort(datestring, new Comparator<String>() {
        DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy '@'hh:mm a");
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            try {
                return f.parse(o1).compareTo(f.parse(o2));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
            }
        }
    });
```

Could you help me?
Thanks.

**Edit1 :**

```
Collections.sort(tmpListPlanning, new Comparator<Planning>() {
            DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss");
            @Override
            public int compare(Planningo1, Planning o2) {
                String date1 = o1.getStart();
                String date2 = o2.getStart();
                try {
                    Log.e("Debug", "RETURN");
                    return f.parse(date1).compareTo(f.parse(date2));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    Log.e("Debug", "Parse Exception");
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
                } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return 0;
            }
        });
```

Comment: *"I couldn't make it work"* How you couldn't make it work? You need a `Comparator<Planning>` instead of `Comparator<String>`.

Comment: I do not believe that format matches the format of your planning list.

Comment: Why are you parsing that date-time string? That format (similar to ISO 8601) when sorted alphabetically happens to also be chronological. No need to parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a list of planning, so you want to compare all the planning.
You need a Planning comparator, and to compare two planning you need to use their start date.

You can try this :

```
Collections.sort(datestring, new Comparator<Planning>() {
        DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy '@'hh:mm a");
        @Override
        public int compare(Planning o1, Planning o2) {
            Date date1 = o1.getStart();
            Date date2 = o2.getStart();
            try {
                return f.parse(date1).compareTo(f.parse(date2));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I edited my original post (I tweaked a bit): It goes through "return f.parse(date1).compareTo(f.parse(date2));" each time but it doesn't modifiy my tmpListPlanning.
 
Did I forget something?

Comment: @Marin Nele. My bad, date1 and date2 aren't String, but Date object.

Comment: It doesn't work tho, it doesn't modify my list. Do you know why?

Comment: Are you sure that no Exception are throw ? Because for me this code work great.

Comment: Check the date format.
You use date into this format "2013-12-10 14:00:00" and you try to parse it into "10/12/2013 14:00:00" So it doesn't work !!

Comment: I also tweeked it in my edit, it's "new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss");" now.

Comment: Check again,  `2013-12-10...` is not parseable with `yyyy/MM/dd...`.